# Bearer token invalid on here fuel prices API even though apikey is included as parameter

Tags: here-api

I am new to Here and am trying to make my first API call but I keep getting back this error:

`{"Type":"Unauthorized","Message":["Bearer token invalid. Bearer missing or bearer value missing."]}`

Here's the URL that I'm using to call the API:

`https://fuel-v2.cc.api.here.com/fuel/stations.json?apiKey=${hereApiKey}&prox=${lat},${lng},1600`

I have also tried including the api key in an authorization header and get the exact same thing. I've tried with `apikey=` and `apiKey=` and the results are the same. I've also tried moving the `apikey` param to after the `prox` param (though I know that shouldn't matter). I feel like I'm following the documentation when it says that I can use api key authentication for this call and that app code authentication is deprecated, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I am currently on a Here Freemium plan and making this call from a Node JS server application.

Comment: Can you please include the link of documentation you followed for this.?

Comment: Here's a link for the documentation about how to use the API key. I followed the note at the bottom about not needing app code credentials.https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication/dev_guide/topics/api-key-credentials.html

Comment: Here's the documentation with the information on how to use the fuel prices API even though here it shows that I need to use the app code credentials. I don't see an app code in my account console so I just assumed that I could use apikey authentication instead as indicated in the previous document. https://developer.here.com/documentation/fuel-prices/dev_guide/topics/resource-stations.html

Answer (score 0):

The token expires in 24 hours, you need to generate a new token and test again

Answer (score 0):

In order to use OAuth token authentication please use the below request

```
https://fuel-v2.cc.ls.api.here.com/fuel/stations.xml?prox=52.516667,13.383333,5000
```

And in header please include

> Authorization = Bearer "Oauth token"

other way to include the token is -
[image]
https://developer.here.com/documentation/fuel-prices/dev_guide/topics/request-here-environments.html